# Como agrupar por mês com SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-select

Tenho uma tabela, por exemplo, com um atributo `nome` e `data` (apenas para caso de exemplo).

Gostaria de gerar uma consulta que me retorne a quantidade de cada linha agrupada por nome e mês:

```
Nome Janeiro Fev Março Abril Maio ...
João  1       0   3     4      5  ...
Lucas 0       2   4     10     1  ...
```

Sei fazer essa consulta separada:

```
SELECT nome, count(extract month from data) jan 
FROM tabela 
WHERE extract month FROM data = 1 
GROUP BY nome
```

Gostaria de fazer tudo em uma consulta só.

Comment: Qual o seu resultado esperado?

Comment: marlon, o resultado esperado é a tabela que coloquei acima. Minha consulta separada vai retornar apenas o més de janeiro, gostaria que os outros meses estivessem na mesma consulta tbm.

Comment: http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/515040-listar-quantidade-de-pedidos-por-ms-sem-repetir-cliente/     veja se ajuda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aqui está a solução:
Postei ela no http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a04f8/8, simulando com PostgreSQL 9.3.1, mas acredito eu que funciona com todos os bancos, com Oracle, SQL Server e PostgreSQL irão funcionar.

Explicando o conceito: como você deseja saber quantos registro tem para cada pessoa no mês, agrupo o SQL por pessoa, e depois faço o case com sum para ter a regra que desejo e mostrar a quantidade de itens por mês agrupado por pessoa.

O bom deste SQL, que ele é simples e não pesa no banco de dados.

Modelo

```
create table temp 
(
  nome varchar(50),
  data date
)
```

Dados para teste:

```
insert into temp values ('Maria', '2014-02-01');
insert into temp values ('Maria', '2014-02-01');
insert into temp values ('Maria', '2014-02-01');
insert into temp values ('Maria', '2014-03-01');
insert into temp values ('Maria', '2014-04-01');
insert into temp values ('Maria', '2014-04-01');

insert into temp values ('João', '2014-04-01');
insert into temp values ('João', '2014-06-01');
insert into temp values ('João', '2014-07-01');
insert into temp values ('Maria', '2014-04-01');
```

SQL para o resultado:

```
SELECT 
  nome, 
  sum(case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data)= 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Jan,
  sum(case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data)= 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Fev,
  sum(case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data)= 3 then 1 else 0 end) as Mar,
  sum(case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data)= 4 then 1 else 0 end) as Abr,
  sum(case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data)= 5 then 1 else 0 end) as Mai,
  sum(case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data)= 6 then 1 else 0 end) as Jun,
  sum(case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data)= 7 then 1 else 0 end) as Jul,
  sum(case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data)= 8 then 1 else 0 end) as Ago,
  sum(case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data)= 9 then 1 else 0 end) as Set,
  sum(case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data)= 10 then 1 else 0 end) as Out,
  sum(case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data)= 11 then 1 else 0 end) as Nov,
  sum(case when EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data)= 12 then 1 else 0 end) as Dez
FROM 
  temp
group by
  nome
```

Comment: Exatamente, Obrigado Marlon.